# Add docker-compose to system path Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker-compose, system-paths

How do I add a `C:\{some_path}\docker-compose` file to system path in Windows 10? Currently, I am running it by navigating to the path in *cmd* and entering command **docker-compose up**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check out the instructions listed here:

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Make sure you add the correct path for `docker-compose`. It will work

Comment: This example modifies path for java, you can do for docker also in the same way.

Comment: I already have added `C:/{some_path}/` to *Path*. However, when I try to run docker from anywhere, it gives me this error.

`Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent. Are you in the right directory? Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml`

Comment: So the directory where you run docker-compose, does it have the correct docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: Yes, docker file exists at `C:/{some_path}/docker-compose.yml`. My system path contains an entry of `C:/{some_path}/`. But when I try to run, using `docker-compose up` command using cmd (from anywhere other than navigating to `C:/{some_path}/` folder, it gives me error saying **"Can't find suitable config file in this directory..."**.